# MongoDB restore works on CLI but not inside BASH

Tags: mongodb

I don't know why a command that runs OK in the command line, gives an error inside a bash script.

> mongorestore -h XXXX.mongohq.com:10025 -u USER -p PASS -db pr4
>   DIC24/pr4

This works OK on the CLI, but inside a bash script I get:

Mon Dec 24 19:48:52 ERROR: don't know what to do with file [DIC24/pr4]

Answer (score 1):

I found that the BASH changed the working dir in another line (I was editing a bash file created by other) so the script was running in another directory.

Comment: Indeed, just like cronjobs (like PHP cronjob) bash actually changes the directory to `/` normally. You can add your directory to the paths by setting the system path but normally it is better to just code around it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing all the details of your connection screen, but watch out for special bash characters. When automating some console commands I ran via Bash Scripting I ran into issues because one of the credentials contained an exclamation point.

Another thought: are you executing the script from the directory it's stored in?